# IE Automation selecting dropdown list option and refresh page with Powershell

Tags: powershell, automation, getelementbyid

I am working on some IE automation where it pulls up a webpage and modifies options on the page. These are things like text boxes, radio buttons, and drop down list boxes. I am able to modify the options using something like this

```
$name = $doc.GetElementByID("name").value = "Bob"
```

However on this page there is a dropdown list box and when you change it manually a new set of options appear.  If I use the above command to pick an option, the option changes, however the page doesn't refresh to make the new options appear so I can modify those.   Is there anyway to "refresh" the page so the new options appear after selection the option in the drop down list box?

Comment: Do you own the webpage? If you do you need to check if some script is not triggered by the list's value change, and try to trigger it yourself. If you don't, I'm not sure you can achieve this.

Comment: Its not my webpage, it a configuration page for a device.  It has this in the tag onchange="usermodified=true so not sure if I can trigger the event with powershell or not

Comment: Is it a public URL, so one can test ? In the cases with complex user experience selenium is more efficient.

Comment: Its an internal site, however I found and example of something here using the same code.  Its a javascript onchange. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange  Wondering if i can fire the event using powershell

Answer (score 0):

I am using this bit of code to fire the change event in my code, it works in some cases and might steer you in the right direction.

The w3school example page you provided is acting strange and I cannot find elements correctly, probably something to do with the iFrame it's using.

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'
$ie.Visible= $true
$ie.Navigate("https://www.website.com")


#wait for IE
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true -or $ie.Document -eq $null ){Start-Sleep -seconds 1;} 


$dropDown = $ie.Document.getElementByID( 'mySelect')
$dropDown.value = 2
$dropDown.FireEvent('onchange')
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for the website in your example (tested on powershell 5):

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject internetexplorer.application
$ie.Visible = $true
$ie.Navigate("https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange")
while ($ie.Busy) {Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500}
$ie.Document.getElementById("iframeResult").contentDocument.getElementById("mySelect")[1].selected = $true
$ie.Document.getElementById("iframeResult").contentDocument.getElementById("mySelect").FireEvent("onchange")
```